# Magento2 Varnish configurations for mobile

Tags: magento2, varnish, mobile

I am using varnish with magento2. however by default  **VCL** doesn’t include device detection and assumes that websites are responsive so that the mobile and desktop browser would be served the same page.
How do I change varnish config so that it saves cache based on user-agent?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding below changes to the subroutines in default.vcl

```
sub vcl_recv {

    if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "iP(?:hone|ad|od)|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera (?:Mini|Mobi)") {
         set req.http.X-Device = "mobile";
    } else {
         set req.http.X-Device = "other";
    }

}

sub vcl_hash {

    if (req.http.X-Device) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Device);
    }

}

sub vcl_deliver {

    set resp.http.X-Varnish-Device = req.http.X-Device;

}
```